# how to translate this sql queries to Core Data

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nspredicate

How to convert the sql queries into predicates or fetch requests,

> ```
> select a.name 
> from a 
> group by a.name;
> ```

Answer (score 1):

It is a possible solution:

```
NSFetchRequest* request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"a"];
[request setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"name"]];
[request setPropertiesToGroupBy:@[@"name"]];
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
```

Comment: That works, but I wonder why.  The documentation states that each of those request properties should an array of type NSPropertyDescription (not an array of strings).

Comment: Here is the answer http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CoreDataSnippets/Articles/fetchExpressions.html

Comment: Hmmm... I don't see the answer there.  Except in one case (which is not explained), NSPropertyDescription is used.